# Populate textbox on different form from data in a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to populate data from a `DataGridView` into `TextBoxes` which are on a different `form`. I can  populate `TextBoxes` that are on the same form as the `DataGridView`. I'm not sure on how to reference the other form?
My code :

```
var value = dgvInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Description"].Value;

if (value != null)
{
    txtDescription.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
The possible duplicate question deals with passing data from one `TextBox` to another. In my question it is passing data from a `DataGridView` to a `TextBox`.

Comment: is your second form is already open? or you first open form on button click and then populate?

Comment: Hi Thanks, Its a button click then opens the second form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `Value` as constructor parameter to destination form (for example `Form4`):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Form4 fr = new Form4(dgvInfo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Description"].Value.ToString());
    fr.ShowDialog();
}
```

And in the destination form:

```
public Form4(string p)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtDescription.Text = p;
}
```

To pass more than one value to another form you should use a `List` like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvInfo.SelectedRows)
    {
        var Value = row.Cells["Description"].Value.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value))
        {
            lst.Add(Value);
        }
    }
    Form4 fr = new Form4(lst);
    fr.ShowDialog();
}
```

And then in destination form:

```
public Form4(List<string> p)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtDescription.Text = p[0];
    textBox1.Text = p[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, what if there was more then one`Row` and `textbox`?

Comment: @AndroidAL.. Run project and select two row for example then click on button.